# How to format JSON correctly with arrays

Tags: arrays, json, http, go, request

I'm trying to send a JSON payload in my POST request but I'm not sure on how to format it correctly to use arrays. This below is what the **correct JSON** itself looks like:

```
{
    "animal": "dog",
    "contents": [{
        "name": "daisy",
        "VAL": "234.92133",
        "age": 3
    }]
}
```

I have this so far:

```
        group := map[string]interface{}{
            "animal": "dog",
            "contents": map[string]interface{}{
                "name": "daisy",
                "VAL":  "234.92133",
                "age":  3,
            },
        }
```

But I can't figure out how to do array of contents (the square brackets), only the curly brackets from "contents".

Comment: Read about slices at [A Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/7)

Comment: And for JSON, structs are usually much easier and better than string/interface{} maps.

Answer (score 6):

The quick answer:

```golang
    group := map[string]interface{}{
        "animal": "dog",
        "contents": []map[string]interface{}{
            {
                "name": "daisy",
                "VAL":  "234.92133",
                "age":  3,
            },
        },
    }
```

But as already said in the comments it is better (type safety) to use structs instead:

```golang
type Animal struct {
    Type     string          `json:"animal"`
    Contents []AnimalContent `json:"contents"`
}

type AnimalContent struct {
    Name  string `json:"name"`
    Value string `json:"VAL"`
    Age   int    `json:"age"`
}
```

Then create with:

```golang
    group := Animal{
        Type:     "dog",
        Contents: []AnimalContent{
            {
                Name:  "daisy",
                Value: "234.92133",
                Age:   3,
            },
        },
    }

    // to transform to json format
    bts, err := json.Marshal(group)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(bts))
```